# "Vague to convey my meaning" or "too vague to convey my meaning"

Tags: adverbs, sentence-structure

I wrote:

> It seems my words were **too** vague to convey my meaning.

What if I write it as:

> It seems my words were vague to convey my meaning.

Is it yet correct? What's their difference?

Comment: "*How about* if I write it as ...." or "*What* if I write it as ....?

Answer (score 8):

The word *too* is a deictic degree adverb. These kinds of adverbs usually modify adjectives or other adverbs. In the following examples, the word *too* is represented by X:

- It's X hot in here.
- This hat is X big.
- You are walking X fast.

X here represents the extent (or the "degree") of the hotness, the bigness and the fastness in the sentences above. In other words it represents *how* hot it was, *how* big the hat is and *how* fast the person is walking. Notice that it doesn't give us exact information. We don't know the temperature in the room, the exact size  of the hat, or the exact speed that the person is walking. When we use the adverb *too* like this we understand that the extent causes some kind of problem. So it is so hot that it is a problem, the hat is so big that there is a problem. The person is walking so fast that there is a problem. We have an idea about how hot, big or fast the thing is from the context.

However, deictic degree adverbs like this can also sometimes take a clause. This clause works as a semantic index. It tells us the extent or degree represented by the adverb.

- It was **so** hot [that I fainted].
- She was **that** late [that we had to cancel the appointment].

In the sentences above, we understand the extent of the hotness because we understand that it caused me to faint. In the second sentence we understand the extent of the lateness because it caused them to cancel their appointment.

The adverb *too* can also take a clause as a semantic index. This clause shows something that can't happen—or didn't happen, or won't happen—because of the extent involved:

- The piano was **too** heavy [(for us) to carry].

In the sentence above, we understand how heavy the piano was because of the clause at the end of the sentence. It was so heavy that it prevented us from carrying it.

**The Original Poster's question**

> It seems my words were **too** vague [to convey my meaning].

In the sentence above, the clause in brackets, [ ], tells us *how* vague the words were. They were so vague that this prevented them from conveying the author's meaning.

Now this clause at the end is a(n indirect) Complement of the word *too*. This means that the word *too* creates a special slot, a special space, for this clause at the end of the sentence. The purpose of the clause at the end is to provide the semantic index so that we understand *how* vague the words were. If we take the word *too* away, we don't have any special reason to use the clause at the end any more. For this reason, the following sentence does not work well:

> It seems my words were vague [to convey my meaning].

---

<sup>**Grammar Note**</sup>

<sup>This *could* be a meaningful and grammatical sentence, but then it would mean something like:</sup>

<sup>- Compared to the words that I could have used to convey my meaning, these words were vague.</sup>

<sup>So this sentence does not mean that the vagueness stopped the words from conveying the meaning. This sentence has a completely different meaning from the Original Poster's first sentence. It is also an unlikely reading. 
It is almost definitely not what the Original Poster wants to say.</sup>

Comment: I'm struggling to grasp how you parse the infinitival to derive the sense "compared to the words that normally convey my meaning". Even the EModE *X to Y* = *X compared to Y* ("Hyperion to a satyr!") requires that X and Y both be nominals. The only grammatical parsing I can see would take it to be an infinitival of purpose, and that would be semantically contradictory.

Comment: As for *It seems my words were vague to convey my meaning*, I would paraphrase it like this: _In order to convey my meaning, I used vague words_. Of course, that seems like a contradiction, which I think is everyone's point.

Comment: @StoneyB I was thinking along the lines of "He's very young to be a soldier" .

Comment: Wow, that never occurred to me. Props+.

Comment: @J.R. Perhaps see my comment to Stoney above, and his edit in his answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Your rewrite is ungrammatical.<sup>†</sup>

Syntactically, the infinitival verb phrase *to convey my meaning* does not modify *vague* by itself; it is a component of the construction *too ADJ to VP* and depends on *too* to be meaningful.

> How vague were my words? They were ***too*** vague ***to convey my meaning***.

<sup>†</sup>ADDED:
Araucaria gives a possible parsing of *∅ vague to convey my meaning* which would in fact make it grammatical and meaningful = approximately "My words are at best on the vague end of the spectrum of words which might conceivably convey my meaning". He's right—but this use is very unlikely to occur in this context, and I'm pretty sure it's not what you mean!

Comment: The other answers say the second sentence is yet grammatical, though they interpret it differently from each other.

Comment: @Ahmad The other answer is correct. Your second version is grammatical, but would indicate something slightly different, and in most contexts would not make sense.

Comment: @Ahmad -- see my addition.

Answer (score 3):

> It seems my words were too vague to convey my meaning.
>
> It seems my words were vague to convey my meaning.

Grammatically, both the sentences are correct though the latter is nonsensical.

The word "too" as an adverb  suggests an excessive or undesirable amount. When used in this senese in the construction too + adjective + to infinitive, we  are saying that a particular result doesn't or cannot happen.

So the first sentence means that "It seems that my words were so vague that they didn't convey my meaning".

As for the second sentence, you can use an adjective + to infinitive to convey your opinion or a reason.  So the second sentence means "It seems that my words were vague because they conveyed my meaning", which doesn't make sense.  However, you can say:

It seems that my words were clear enough to convey my meaning (= It seems that my words were clear because they conveyed my meaning).

Ad for alternatives to your first sentence, you can say:

It seems my words were so vague that they didn't connvey my meaning.

It seems my words were not clear enough to convey my meaning.

Comment: Interesting interpretation. However the other answers have opposite interpretation for the second sentence. It also seems you may need "clear enough to convey my meaning". Not?

Comment: @Ahmad, As an alternatives to your first sentence, you can say "my words were not clear to convey my meaning" or "my words were so vague that they didn't convey my meaning".

Comment: If I heard "my words were clear to convey my meaning" I would immediately assume that the speaker was non-native.

Comment: @walt how about "clear enough to convey my meaning"?

Comment: @Ahmad That's perfect and much more natural to my ear.

Answer (score 2):

> It seems my words were too vague to convey my meaning.

You need to explain or qualify the use of the word *vague*. You could say: My meaning was vague. I prefer *too vague* because it better explains what you are saying and my example is not better at all, just grammatically correct.

*It seems my words were too vague to convey my meaning.*  This is a better sentence.

ON EDIT: The definition of the word *vague* is:[not clearly stated, described, or explained, or not clearly seen or felt:](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/vague) or (the google definition): of uncertain, indefinite, or unclear character or **meaning**.

So you are already saying that the meaning is unclear by using the word *vague*. This is why the word *too* works. It enhances the use of the word to make it more explanatory.

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider the sentences without the deictic **too** in terms of *cause and effect*.

> The coach's tone was **harsh** to convey his displeasure.
>
> She was **happy** to hear her name called.

How can we distinguish between the two infinitival complements, the first expressing *purpose*, the second expressing *cause*? (The coach's purpose, in using a harsh tone, was to express his displeasure. The *cause* of her happiness was that she heard her name called.) We look at the verb (hear, convey) and we have to examine the adjective that licenses the infinitival and determine whether it can be purposeful. It is something *intentional*? Can it be a *result*?

When we see a sentence like

> His words were vague to reveal his meaning.
>
> His words were vague to conceal his meaning.

how can we know whether the infinitival complement refers to a purpose or to a cause? Again, we look at the adjective and ask whether it can cause the infinitival or result from the infinitival.

Can we be vague in order to reveal our meaning? No. Can we be vague in order to conceal our meaning? Yes. Can revealing or concealing our meaning cause us to be vague? No.

Comment: I like your example using _conceal_ in place of _reveal_ – now **that's** a sentence that would make sense.